# can anybody help me depict this php code line by line: functions & recursions

Tags: php

```
function f2($n, $a)
{
    if ($n == 0)
      return 0;
   return $a + f2($n-1, $a); // Changed return a... to return $a...
}

echo f2(3,4);
```

this outputs 12, I just don't understand why. Here's what  I think, though:

obviously, $n and $a are the variables that will be take the place of the values. so like n is 3 and a is 4 in this example. the base case is the if statement, and it acts like a loop between the n. so since n is 3, and n is set to = 0 , then the code loops 3 times.

now i dont get the return a + f2(n-1, a) part. obviously that's where the math is calculated, but how?

it loops like this i think:

```
4 + f2(2, 4)
4 + f2(1, 4)
4 + f2(0, 4)
```

but what does it add to make the sum 12??

so what im asking is that if i understand it correctly and if not, what's actually happening and how is the output 12.

Comment: Try echoing `a + f2($n-1, $a);` right above your return, see what happens.

Comment: sure, let me try it.

Comment: it echoes:

    4 + f2(3-1, 4) 
    4 + f2(2-1, 4) 
    4 + f2(1-1, 4)

Comment: I assume it's `$a + f2($n-1, $a)` instead  of `a + f2($n-1, $a)`

Comment: _Warning: Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a'_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first call is `f2(3,4)`

```
f2(3,4)
    |
  return 4 + f(2,4)
                |
             return 4 + f(1,4)
                          |
                        return 4 + f(0, 4)
                                       |
                                   return 0; // and now unwinding the stack, 0 gets passed to the prev. return called.
                                       |
                        return 4 +     0   // 4 gets passed to the prev. return called
                          |
             return 4 + 4 + 0         // 8 gets passed to the prev. return called.
                |
  return 4 + 4 + 4 + 0    // f2(3,4) now returns a value of 12
```

looking at the call stack above , the first return called will be :

`return 4 + 4 + 4 + 0`

`return a + call f2` , the `+` operator chains the `a` with the next function call, which at the end accumulates all your intermediate values in the first `return` called.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the following about your "loop interpretation"...

> the base case is the if statement, and it acts like a loop between the
>   n. so since n is 3, and n is set to = 0 , then the code loops 3 times.

There is no loop there. It just states the function returns the value 0 when $n = 0.

What does happen is the function calling itself 3 times at line `return a + f2($n-1, $a);` while decrementing $n.

As stated above, the calling stops when $n = 0 and value 0 is returned.

So you calling the function first + the function calling itself 3 times results in:

```
4 + f2(2,4)
4 + 4 + f2(1,4)
4 + 4 + 4 + f2(0,4)
4 + 4 + 4 + 0; // 12
```